# get command output of container using ansible docker_container module

Tags: ansible

I'd like using ansible [docker_container](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html) to generate influxdb config file.
which will act the same as below docker command

`docker run --rm influxdb influxd config > /opt/influxdb/config/influxdb.conf`

I created a task on my playbook as below

```
  - name: generate influxdb config using temporary container
    docker_container:
      name: influxdb_conf
      state: present
      image: influxdb:1.4
      command: influxd config > /tmp/influxdb.conf
      volumes:
        - "/opt/influxdb/config:/tmp"
```

when I check the output path `/opt/influxdb/config`, it is empty.
how can I get the `influxd config` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute `/bin/sh` as command and also you may want to use `detach` and `cleanup`:

```
  - name: generate influxdb config using temporary container
    docker_container:
      name: influxdb_conf
      state: started
      image: influxdb:1.4
      command: "/bin/sh -c 'influxd config > /tmp/influxdb.conf'"
      detach: no
      interactive: yes
      tty: yes
      recreate: yes
      cleanup: yes
      volumes:
        - /opt/influxdb/config:/tmp
```

Comment: also I need to change `state: started`

Answer (score 2):

You can register the module and use ansible_facts to get the logs in next task as below

```
- name: generate influxdb config using temporary container
  docker_container:
    name: influxdb_conf
    state: present
    image: influxdb:1.4
    command: influxd config > /tmp/influxdb.conf
    volumes:
      - "/opt/influxdb/config:/tmp"
  register: docker

- name: display logs
  debug:
    msg:  "{{ docker.ansible_facts.docker_container.Output }}"
```